# Merging multiple Objects With Unique Keys

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, implementation

Given 2 or more objects, I need to create a function that will merge all of the properties with unique keys into one object without using most higher order functions like filter(), map(), reduce(), etc.

For some reason my code still will add in properties that may have the same keys as the destination object's keys. Here's what I got:

```js
_.defaults = function(obj) {
  var objectArray = Array.from(arguments);
  var resultObject = objectArray[0];
  for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
    if(Object.keys(resultObject)!==(Object.keys(objectArray[i]))){
      Object.assign(resultObject, objectArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return resultObject;
};
```

I also tried this on line 5, to no avail

```js
  

if(Object.keys(resultObject).includes(Object.keys(objectArray[i])) === false){
```

Comment: Objects/Arrays can be compared with == or ===
As they are reference comparison, it will return false.
Furthermore, about the question, Can you tell what will happen if a key exist in object 1 and in object 2 both, Should this key be part of result or not

As in: {a:1} and {a: 1, b: 2} what is the expected output here?

Comment: So if you're given something like obj1 = {x:3}, obj2 = {a:1, x:5, :y:2}, obj3 = {c:3, y:4}, result = {x:3, a:1, y:2, c:3}. It takes the the object that has the first occurrence of a key

Comment: I hope you are doing this exercise only to learn from it. In projects, you should reuse existing implementations as much as possible rather than writing your own. But I do want to facilitate the learning so I have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Half of your problem is in this line:

```
    if(Object.keys(resultObject)!==(Object.keys(objectArray[i])))
```

This condition *always* evaluates to `true`. The reason for this is that `Object.keys` returns an array. Arrays are compared by reference; that means that the `==`, `===`, `!==`, etcetera operators only check whether the left hand array is the same object as the right hand array. There is no comparison of contents. Since `Object.keys` returns a *new* array every time, there is no way in which the two arrays could compare equal.

However, even if this was a comparison by contents, it would not do what you want. For example, consider these two objects:

```
// resultObject
{ a: 1, b: 2 }

// objectArray[i]
{ b: 3, c: 4 }
```

The condition would evaluate `['a', 'b'] !== ['b', 'c']` which is `true` regardless of whether you compare by reference or by contents.

Your second attempt has the same problem of always evaluating to `true`. To see why, let's substitute the results of `Object.keys`:

```
if(['a', 'b'].includes(['b', 'c']) === false)
```

The `includes` method basically asks the following question: "is any of my elements equal to the argument?" Since `Object.keys` always produces an array of strings, you're asking whether any of those strings is equal to an array, which it is never going to be. The left hand of the `===` is always `false`, so the condition as a whole will always be `true`.

As a result, you always end up doing this (the other half of your problem):

```
      Object.assign(resultObject, objectArray[i]);
```

in the above example, this overrides the `b` key on the `resultObject`, since `Object.assign` has no way to know that you want to skip the keys that were already set.

Intuitively, what you want is to check whether there are any keys in `objectArray[i]` that aren't yet in `resultObject` and then assign *only those keys* on the `resultObject`. This means that you have to consider the keys of `objectArray[i]` one by one.

The following code will do that:

```
    var currentObject = objectArray[i];
    var keys = Object.keys(currentObject);
    for (var l = keys.length, j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      var key = keys[j];
      if (resultObject[key] === undefined) {
        resultObject[key] = currentObject[key];
      }
    }
```

You can substitute this for the entire `if`-statement in your original code and then it should work.